# My Matplotlib subplot title removes itself

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run my code I create a figure, then I create a subplot in that figure. Then when I try to add a title to it using `ax.set_title("title")` it sometimes shows up for a split second then goes away. I have tried using `plot.title` aswell with no luck.

I tried recreating the error in a small example but for some reason it worked just fine there, so here is the entire source code of the code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.style as style
import plotgen
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class plotWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        style.use("bmh")
        self.dp = 30

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, label="ax1")


        self.cax = 1
        self.maxax = 2
        self.minax = 1

        plotgen.clear("plot1.txt")
        plotgen.clear("plot2.txt")

        axnext = plt.axes([0.80, 0.01, 0.06, 0.06])
        axprev = plt.axes([0.73, 0.01, 0.06, 0.06])

        bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next >')
        bnext.on_clicked(self.changePlotNext)
        bprev = Button(axprev, "< Previous")
        bprev.on_clicked(self.changePlotPrev)


        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=500)
        plt.show()

    def changePlotNext(self, i):
        if self.cax < self.maxax:
            self.cax += 1
            self.ax.set_title("Pump " + str(self.cax))

    def changePlotPrev(self, i):
        if self.cax > self.minax:
            self.cax -= 1
            self.ax.set_title("Pump " + str(self.cax))

    def animate(self, i):
        if self.cax == 1:
            plotgen.generate("plot1.txt")
            graph_data = open('plot1.txt', 'r').read()
            lines = graph_data.split('\n')
            xs = []
            ys = []
            for line in lines:
                if len(line) > 1:
                    x, y = line.split(',')
                    xs.append(x)
                    ys.append(float(y))
            self.ax.clear()
            lx = len(xs)
            ly = len(ys)
            if len(xs) < self.dp:
                pxs = xs
                pys = ys
            else:
                pxs = xs[(lx - (self.dp - 1)):(lx - 1)]
                pys = ys[(ly - (self.dp - 1)):(ly - 1)]
            self.ax.plot(pxs, pys, "r")
        elif self.cax == 2:
            plotgen.generate("plot2.txt")
            graph_data = open('plot2.txt', 'r').read()
            lines = graph_data.split('\n')
            xs = []
            ys = []
            for line in lines:
                if len(line) > 1:
                    x, y = line.split(',')
                    xs.append(x)
                    ys.append(float(y))
            self.ax.clear()
            lx = len(xs)
            ly = len(ys)
            if len(xs) <= self.dp:
                pxs = xs
                pys = ys
            else:
                pxs = xs[(lx - (self.dp - 1)):(lx - 1)]
                pys = ys[(ly - (self.dp - 1)):(ly - 1)]
            self.ax.plot(pxs, pys)
plotWindow()
```

As you can see in my `changePlotNext` and `changePlotPrev` functions I'm trying to change the title. Sometimes they display for a split second when I change, but then it goes away. And I am very aware that I have not set a title to display before I change the plot.

Comment: can you share the block of code? check here on how to make a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You will need to add more information so we can help you. More code for a start...Take a look at this link > https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried recreating it but it worked on that small scale so I don't understand where the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `animate`, you have `self.ax.clear()`, which is removing all artists, texts, etc. on the Axes, including the title.

A simple option, then, is to reset the title after you clear the axes. So if you add:

```
 self.ax.set_title("Pump " + str(self.cax))
```

in both places, immediately after you call `self.ax.clear()`, your titles will still be shown.

Another option would be to stop clearing the axes, but just remove the items you need to remove. I think this is just the lines you have plotted? So, for example, you could remove the call to `self.ax.clear()`, and add:

```
for line in self.ax.lines:
    line.remove()
```

in its place. That will remove just the plotted line, but retain the title.

Comment: I thought about the clearing thing earlier but I put the `self.ax.set_title` in the wrong place. Thank you!